# Extract values from a field to a list in Python (arcpy)

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool

I have a define function ( uniqueList ) in a module which sets the unique values from a list. I'm importing the function to a new script to set the unique values from a field 'COVER', after i've set the SearchCursor and when i run it, it doesn't work.

The define function :

```
def uniqueList(L):
    '''Find the set of unique entries in a list.'''
    S = set(L)
    # Copy S back to L
    U = list(S)
    return U
```

The script :

```
import sys, os
pathDir = os.path.abspath('C:\Gispy\Sample_scripts\Sample_scripts\ch16\exercises\listManage')
dirName = os.path.dirname(pathDir)
relativePath = 'listManage'
modulePath = os.path.join(dirName, relativePath)
sys.path.append(modulePath)
import listManager2
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/gispy/data/ch16/park.shp'
field = arcpy.da.SearchCursor('park.shp', ['COVER'])
value = listManager2.uniqueList(field)
```

Comment: Your first path has wrong slashes. Either \\, / or r'\'

Comment: Please describe what's the error ? As @Matte said one of the error in your code is the backslash syntax. What's listmanager2 ?

Comment: it doesn't print any error, returns exit code 0.

Comment: but when i itterate the result it brings the attributes from the field.

Comment: try it then check error:  os.path.abspath(r'C:\Gispy\Sample_scripts\Sample_scripts\ch16\exercises\listManage')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks a bit complicated. Perhaps your problem is the paths. Use the r (raw) syntax for the paths and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Also you cant set arcpy.env.workspace to a shapefile. You can set it to the folder containing the shapefile or you can set it to a geodatabase.

```
import arcpy,os

path = r'C:\shapefile_folder'
shapefile = r'Polygons.shp'
#If you want to set the workspace (not needed if you use full path and name of shapefile in cursor):
#arcpy.env.workspace = path
fieldname=r'COVER'

def uniqueList(L):
    '''Find the set of unique entries in a list.'''
    S = set(L)
    # Copy S back to L
    U = list(S)
    return U
#List comprehension:
all_entries = [i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(os.path.join(path,shapefile),fieldname)]
```

Call function:

```
uniqueList(all_entries)
```

If you are only doing it once you dont need a function:

```
unique_values_list = list(set([i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(os.path.join(path,shapefile),fieldname)]))
```

Or with set comprehension (curly brackets):

```
unique_values_list = list({i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(os.path.join(path,shapefile),fieldname)}
```